# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] and ngRoute Error in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am having a problem with a controller that doesn't connect with the server.
I solved alot of errors but still I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

I searched and I found out that I need to use ngRoute. I used the CDN in the html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

and in the controller JS file:

```
var courseApp = angular.module('courseApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'seeMoreFilter', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);
```

but still it gaveme the same error

I installed it with npm

> npm install --save angular-route@1.7.9

I got another error in addition to the first one:

> angular-route.js:102 Uncaught TypeError: b.module(...).info is not a
>   function

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you are trying to inject a module that is not available whe the apps loads. Based on the code that you posted I would check this modules `'ui.bootstrap', 'seeMoreFilter', 'ngSanitize'`
because I don't see where are you loading this modules.

Happy coding and stay safe!!!